# Why S.M.A.R.T. Power On Hours Count seems capped at 31847 on most Hard Drives?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have many hard drives used for very long time. Despite different producers (WD, Seagate and Toshiba) and different sizes and warranty policies, all hard drives show no more than 31847 hours of usage.
Is there any specific reason for this max cap on power on hours count attribute of S.M.A.R.T.?

Comment: I have not observed or heard of such a limit. I have a WD drive with 40839 hours. I have seen numbers reported on a forum that were much higher. http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/986215-Longest-quot-Power-On-Hours-quot-for-your-hard-drives

Comment: Maybe the tool you use to display the SMART data has the limit?

Comment: @Aganju I have checked the smart status with the OS shell.